# Run python scripts in virtual environment using optirun

Tags: python, virtualenv, nvidia

How may one run a python tool that uses a virtual environment and an library like [click](http://click.pocoo.org/) if the tool requires the dedicated GPU which is only available via [bumblebee](https://wiki.mageia.org/en/Bumblebee) or `optirun`?

Example:

```
#normally (with nvidia driver being the default)
agent --run-with-tf-gpu train
```

the `agent` script triggers the *click* based application which then uses the `venv/bin/python` binary.

I have a solution (see answer below) but I am happy to award a better one with the "right answer"

Answer (score 0):

### Option 1: replace binary with wrapper

```
p=`pwd`
cd venv/bin
rm python #soft link to python3.6
echo 'optirun $p/venv/bin/python3.6 "$*"' > python
chmod +x python
```

### Option 2: create aliases

only works if python is not called with an absolute path.

Insert these three lines at the end of the `venv/bin/activate` file:

```
#setting optirun to be used when running python in venv
alias python="optirun python"
alias python3="optirun python3"
```

### Option 3: turn card on and off before and after

according to the [arch wiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Bumblebee#CUDA_without_Bumblebee) the following will also enable the card globally so one may easily use IDEs that otherwise perform some complex call with absolute paths etc:

```
tee /proc/acpi/bbswitch <<< ON
```

Now when you start a CUDA application it is going to automatically load all the necessary modules.

To turn off the nvidia card after using CUDA do:

```
rmmod nvidia_uvm
rmmod nvidia
tee /proc/acpi/bbswitch <<< OFF
```